# Add more than one resource directory to jetty

Tags: directory, jetty, embedded-jetty

Looking to use multiple static directories with Jetty. When the server runs:

```
  http://localhost:8282/A
  http://localhost:8282/B 
  http://localhost:8282/C
```

- A is placed in X/V/A
- B is placed in Q/Z/B
- C is placed in P/T/C

The following failed:

```java
    ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
    resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{"index.html"});
    resource_handler.setResourceBase(HTML_SITE);

    ResourceHandler resource_handler1 = new ResourceHandler();
    resource_handler1.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{"index.html"});
    resource_handler1.setResourceBase(HTML_CLIENTZONE_SITE);

    // deploy engine
    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();

    String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    webapp.setResourceBase(getWebAppPath());
    webapp.setContextPath("/");


     HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{resource_handler,resource_handler1 ,webapp,  new DefaultHandler()});
    server.setHandler(handlers);
```

How can I add more than one static resource directory?

Answer (score 18):

Since 6.1.12, this is supported by using a ResourceCollection to the WebAppContext's base resource:

```java
Server server = new Server(8282);
WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
context.setContextPath("/");
ResourceCollection resources = new ResourceCollection(new String[] {
    "project/webapp/folder",
    "/root/static/folder/A",    
    "/root/static/folder/B",    
});
context.setBaseResource(resources);
server.setHandler(context);
server.start();
```

To subsequently open a file, use the ServletContext (e.g., WebAppContext), which could be part of an interface definition, such as:

```java
  /**
   * Opens a file using the servlet context.
   */
  public default InputStream open( ServletContext context, String filename ) {
    String f = System.getProperty( "file.separator" ) + filename;
    return context.getResourceAsStream( f );
  }
```

Such as:

```java
  InputStream in = open( context, "filename.txt" );
```

This will open `filename.txt` if it exists in one of the given directories. Note that getResourceAsStream will return `null`, rather than throw an exception, so it's a good idea to check for it:

```java
  public default InputStream validate( InputStream in, String filename )
    throws FileNotFoundException {
    if( in == null ) {
      throw new FileNotFoundException( filename );
    }

    return in;
  }
```

Then you can update the `open` method as follows:

```java
return validate( context.getResourceAsStream( filename ), filename );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to "mount" independent resource directories to arbitrary URIs in the server namespace, using multiple instances of the `DefaultServlet` with independent `resourceBase` configurations is the best choice.

The following snippet will serve URIs `/A/*` from filesystem path `X/V/A` and `/B/*` from filesystem path `Q/Z/B`:

```java
Server server = new Server();
SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
connector.setPort(Integer.parseInt(port));
server.addConnector(connector);

ServletContextHandler servletHandler = new ServletContextHandler(null, "/", true, false);

// Configuration for serving /A/* from X/V/A
DefaultServlet aServlet = new DefaultServlet();
ServletHolder aHolder = new ServletHolder(aServlet);
aHolder.setInitParameter("resourceBase", "X/V/A");
aHolder.setInitParameter("pathInfoOnly", "true");
servletHandler.addServlet(aHolder, "/A/*");

// Configuration for serving /B/* from Q/Z/B
DefaultServlet bServlet = new DefaultServlet();
ServletHolder bHolder = new ServletHolder(bServlet);
bHolder.setInitParameter("resourceBase", "Q/Z/B");
bHolder.setInitParameter("pathInfoOnly", "true");
servletHandler.addServlet(bHolder, "/B/*");

HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { servletHandler });
server.setHandler(handlers);

server.start();
```

Note: As you can see from the code above, there is no need that the name of the directory from which `/A/*` is served is exactly `A` as in your example. Both names - the filesystem name of the directory to serve and the URI to map the contents to - are completely independent.